Nodemailer, 504 Gateway Time-out
I am trying to get nodemailer to work. Locally everything works fine, but not online, not with my front-end and not with postman.co. If I send a request, it takes the origin many seconds to give up and show me a gateway error. The strange thing is, the e-mails I send, do arrive almost instantly despite the error. I am using the domain mail from IONOS. Now after shortening the code, it looks like this:
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ionos.de",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, 
    auth: {
        user: "mail@haselberger-web-development.de",
        pass: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    },
});

general_users.post("/Kontakt", async(req, res, next) => {

    var content = req.body;
    content = JSON.stringify(content)

    await transporter.sendMail({
        from: "mail@haselberger-web-development.de", 
        to: "mail@haselberger-web-development.de",
        subject: "Kundenanfrage", 
        text: content, // plain text body
        html: `<b>${content}</b>`,
    })
});

Any ideas? I am still new to this.
I tried it locally, with my react front-end and with postman.co. I did not use any other mailbox, because I want it to work with the domain mail and local requests do work. In another post I read that passwords are sometimes an issue, so I changed mine to a much weaker version, consisting of letters, nothing else.

I editted the second part. I guess the most important thing was ending the mailing process with end().
.catch((error) => {return res.status(500).json({ error: "message not sent" }).end();})
.then(res.status(200).json({ message: "message sent" }).end())
The origin did not wait any longer for anything and there was no longer a timeout issue.

Explanation in my comment...
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.ionos.de",
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for port 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: "mail@haselberger-web-development.de",
            pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        },
    });
    

general_users.post("/Kontakt", async(req, res, next) => {

    var content = req.body;
    content = JSON.stringify(content)

    await transporter.sendMail({
        from: "mail@haselberger-web-development.de", // sender address
        to: "mail@haselberger-web-development.de", // list of receivers
        subject: "Kundenanfrage", // Subject line
        text: content, // plain text body
        html: `<b>${content}</b>`})
        .catch((error) => {return res.status(500).json({ error: "message not sent" }).end();})
        .then(res.status(200).json({ message: "message sent" }).end())
})

